# Can I save an EXCEL worksheet as CSV via ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

Is it possible to save a worksheet of a workbook as CSV via ClosedXML?

For example:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook(fileName);
IXLWorksheet worksheet;
workbook.Worksheets.TryGetWorksheet(sheetName, out worksheet);
```

How to Save it as CSV?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not possible directly in ClosedXML. You have to use loops or LINQ to build your own CSV file.

For example:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(csvFileName,
    worksheet.RowsUsed().Select(row =>
        string.Join(";", row.Cells(1, row.LastCellUsed(false).Address.ColumnNumber)
                            .Select(cell => cell.GetValue<string>()))
 ));
```

Comment: All columns are write as single column.

Comment: Did you change the ";" to a ","  It works for me when you do.

Answer (score 23):

Other answers will fail to generate a valid CSV if cells have the separator so here is a better way

```
var lastCellAddress = worksheet.RangeUsed().LastCell().Address;
File.WriteAllLines(csvFileName, worksheet.Rows(1, lastCellAddress.RowNumber)
    .Select(r => string.Join(",", r.Cells(1, lastCellAddress.ColumnNumber)
            .Select(cell =>
        {
            var cellValue = cell.GetValue<string>();
            return cellValue.Contains(",") ? $"\"{cellValue}\"" : cellValue;
        }))));
```

This is based on **@Extragorey**'s answer

Comment: Bear in mind Excel cells can also contain the newline/return character, in which case they would also need quotes.  There may be a couple of other trigger characters I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

As @Emanuele points out, @Raidri's answer won't generate a proper CSV format, and it also omits blank rows entirely. To fix this:

```
var lastCellAddress = worksheet.RangeUsed().LastCell().Address;
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(csvFileName, worksheet.Rows(1, lastCellAddress.RowNumber)
    .Select(row => String.Join(",", row.Cells(1, lastCellAddress.ColumnNumber)
        .Select(cell => cell.GetValue<string>()))
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong in

```
row.LastCellUsed(false)
```

it's not a correct format for csv. Last columns will be empty instead of get relative separator.